# Cosmos DB - Do I have to wait for indexing?

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

If I insert a document and, on the next line of code, search it by one of it's fields (other than Id), will I find it? Or do I have to wait for some indexing to happen?

Comment: It'd be nice to get this one closed too so that other people looking for this information can be confident ;)

Comment: @JesseCarter i'm still trying to validate this... since no official document or evidence of any experiment was presented, i decided to run a little experiment myself...

Comment: My answer was based on this documentation from Microsoft which should validate the information I've presented. I'll update the answer to also indicate this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft provides clear documentation around the different types of Indexing Strategies available and how to use them. The information below is a summary of this information.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies)

CosmosDb has multiple indexing strategies. By default, it's set to consistent which means that documents are indexed as they are placed into the collection. New documents should be immediately available for querying. You are free to switch this to lazy indexing mode which indexes when it's more convenient for the database.

It's good to know that with consistent indexing turned on, you will observe a higher RU cost per insert/upsert because the cost of indexing is included. So whether or not consistent or lazy makes sense for you is based on the nature of the app you're building.

You can check the type of indexing you're using in the portal and actually tune indexing by including or excluding specific JSON paths in your documents. This is a really powerful and cool feature in Cosmos. You can see that by default, the settings are `consistent` indexing and a path of `/*` indicates that all JSON properties are covered by the index.

[image]

Comment: By increasing RU cost do you mean each operation on index takes extra RU (which is similar to dynamodb)?